Comparison of Solution Norms for Invertible and Near-Singular Matrices Using Pseudoinverses
I am studying the behavior of solutions to linear systems of equations where the coefficient matrices are either invertible or near-singular. Specifically, I am interested in understanding the norms of the solutions in these two cases.
Suppose we have two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $\|A - B\|$ is small in the usual norm (e.g., Frobenius norm), but $A$ is invertible and $B$ is not.

For the invertible matrix $A$, the unique solution to the system $AX = b$ is given by $X_A = A^{-1} b$.
For the near-singular matrix $B$, the solution in the least-squares sense is given by $X_B = B^+ b$, where $B^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $B$.

My questions are:

How do the norms of these solutions, $\|X_A\|$ and $\|X_B\|$, compare?
What can be said about the stability and sensitivity of these solutions, particularly when $B$ is close to singular?
Are there any theoretical results or references that discuss the behavior of solution norms in such scenarios?

I would appreciate any insights or references that could help me understand the relationship between the norms of the solutions for invertible and near-singular matrices.
